# WMTSLayers seems not working in EPSG:25830

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm developing new web and I want to consume WMTS services with ArcGIS javascript API4

WMTSLayer in Javascript API 4.11 seems not working when spatialReference EPSG:25830 is selected.

The problem is that the request is generating by the API is incorrect, Tilerow parameter is wrong.

The request is being sent is this. http://www.ign.es/wmts/ign-base?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER=IGNBaseTodo&STYLE=default&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG%3A25830&TILEMATRIX=18&TILEROW=236256&TILECOL=32268

And must be...

http://www.ign.es/wmts/ign-base?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER=IGNBaseTodo&STYLE=default&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG%3A25830&TILEMATRIX=18&TILEROW=32374&TILECOL=32268

Here is my code example.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rsjt5nma/1/)

or

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <title>Select WMTSLayer sublayer - 4.11</title>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 95%; /* allow space for sublayer switcher */
        width: 100%;
      }

      select,
      label {
        font-family: "Avenir Next W00", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,
          sans-serif;
      }

      #selectDiv {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      #theLabel {
        visibility: hidden; /* hide until populated */
      }

      .esri-layer-list {
        width: 310px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/"></script>

    <script>
      var map, view;

      require([
        "esri/Map",
  "esri/Basemap",
        "esri/Viewpoint",
        "esri/geometry/Extent",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/WMTSLayer",
  "esri/widgets/LayerList",
        "esri/core/watchUtils"
      ], function(
        Map,
  Basemap,
        Viewpoint,
        Extent,
        MapView,
        WMTSLayer,
  LayerList,
        watchUtils
      ) {
   
  var layerBase = {baseMapLayers: [{id: "basemap-layer", opacity: 1, title: "aaaaa", url: "http://arcgis.bizkaia.eus/arcgis/rest/services/ORTOFOTOS/GOBIERNO_VASCO_2016_AMPLIADO/MapServer", visibility: true, layerType:"ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer"}], title: "Basemap"}
        layer = new WMTSLayer({
          url: "http://www.ign.es/wmts/ign-base"
        });

        map = new Map({
   basemap: Basemap.fromJSON(layerBase),
     });
        view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map
        });
        view.when(function() {
          layerList = new LayerList({
            view: view
          });
          view.ui.add(layerList, "bottom-left");
    layer.load();

          layer.when(function() {
            // add all sublayers to the select element
            layer.sublayers.forEach(function(sublayer, i) {
    if (sublayer.id === "IGNBaseOrto" || sublayer.id === "IGNBaseTodo" )
     selectSublayer.options[ selectSublayer.options.length ] = new Option("(" + i + ") " + sublayer.title, sublayer.id);
            });
   // once populated, show the select element
            var theDiv = document.getElementById("theLabel");
            theDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
          }); // end layer.load function
        });

        // if sublayer is changed, recreate map, view, and widgets using new activeLayer
        document.getElementById("selectSublayer").onchange = function(event) {
   map.removeAll();
   if(event.target.value!==""){
    layer.activeLayer = layer
    .findSublayerById(event.target.value)
    .clone();
    map.layers.add(layer);
   }
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="selectDiv">
      <label id="theLabel">
        Pick a layer from the WMTS catalog
        <select id="selectSublayer"><option value="">No Layers Selected</option></select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To reproduce the error one of the WMTSLayer must be selected from the select box.

There is a workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: you are not specifying the EPSG for the base map, is that correct?
I tried to visualise the overlay and it works fine, is the overlap with the base that causes issues, I think that you need to specify the different EPSG if it is so

Comment: To prove that the issue is with your basemap setup, I tried to use this: map = new Map({ basemap: "streets", layers: [layer] });
If you try this configuration you will see that your layer is correcly overlapped over the street map

Comment: The EPSG is being set inherited by the basemap. The basemap is in EPSG:25830, ETRS89UTM3N. you are watching the basemap, in the top of the page, there is a select box where you can select the wmts service layes to be shown.

Comment: With streets works well because the EPSG is not 28530, is 102100, the problem is when you try to use EPSG:25830, the request of the tiles is being wrong calculated, tilerow parameter is what is wrong

Comment: It is a long time I don't work in GIS so apologies if I am not clear/correct. But when you mesh layers using different projections you need to specify the spatial reference and either the server or the client needs to re-project the layer to the basemap EPSG. So if you use EPSG3857 for base maps like google maps, you need the server to reproject the images on the fly.

Comment: The basemap in the new ESRI api is a TyleLayer: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-TileLayer.html

Comment: I am working on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z9vj276f/2/ it does not work, meaning that loading the base I cannot see the overlay, but there are no network errors (bad requests) like in your example, I simply think that the overlay is not overlapping with the base and therefore not requested at all

Comment: WMTS services are tiled services, and you can use only with the projectos than have defined, the two layers that I have set in the example has the projection of EPSG:25830, and i have proved with other sofware that with this projection works well, the projections for each layer can be viewed with getCapabilities feature.

Comment: Check my answer, I think the limitations are affecting you, according to http://arcgis.bizkaia.net/arcgis/rest/services/ORTOFOTOS/GOBIERNO_VASCO_2016_AMPLIADO/MapServer?f=pjson the version is 10.05, and you might need 10.2 or 10.3.

Comment: you have not set the active layer to the WMTS, so is getting the first one of the layers, this layer does not have EPSG:25830, so is not loading and is not makeing requests. please configure the WMTS layer this form layer = new WMTSLayer({
          url: "http://www.ign.es/wmts/ign-base",  
   activeLayer: {
    id: "IGNBaseTodo",
   }    
         });

Comment: or use this code. https://jsfiddle.net/fn5zt7hm/, thx for trying to solve my problem

Comment: Sorry, arcgis.bizkaia.net is 10.05 use arcgis.bizkaia.eus instead, this is 10.31, the problem persist. http://arcgis.bizkaia.eus/arcgis/rest/services/ORTOFOTOS/GOBIERNO_VASCO_2016_AMPLIADO/MapServer

Answer (score 0):

Your basemap layer type is ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, which in the new API 4.11 is a TileLayer.
According to the documentation of the TileLayer from ESRI:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-TileLayer.html

> Known Limitations
>
> When adding a TileLayer to a map in a SceneView, the following
>   limitations exist:
>
> This layer needs to be published from ArcGIS Server 10.3 and later or
>   ArcGIS Server 10.2.2 with this applied fix. If viewingMode is global,
>   then only services with ArcGIS Online/Bing Maps/Google Maps (Web
>   Mercator) or WGS84 Geographic Coordinate System, Version 2 tiling
>   scheme are supported. If viewingMode is local, then only services with
>   projected coordinate systems are supported. Only Tile layers with the
>   following tiling scheme specifications are supported:
>
> 256x256 or 512x512 pixel tiles Scale levels must increase or decrease
>   by a power of two At level 0 there shouldn't be more than 30 root
>   tiles. All tiled layers must have the same tiling scheme and
>   SpatialReference.

Please find the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z9vj276f/2/) and example which does not work but does not fail either (does not show 400 bad request when loading the layer)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <title>Select WMTSLayer sublayer - 4.11</title>

    <style>
      html,body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 95%; /* allow space for sublayer switcher */
        width: 100%;
      }
      select, label {
        font-family: "Avenir Next W00", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,
          sans-serif;
      }
      #selectDiv {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #theLabel {
        visibility: hidden; /* hide until populated */
      }
      .esri-layer-list {
        width: 310px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/"></script>
    <script>
var map, view, layer;
require([
        "esri/Map",
            "esri/Basemap",        
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/WMTSLayer",
            "esri/widgets/LayerList",
        "esri/layers/TileLayer"
      ], function(Map,Basemap,MapView,WMTSLayer,LayerList,TileLayer) {

var basemap = new Basemap({
  baseLayers: [
    new TileLayer({
    url: "http://arcgis.bizkaia.eus/arcgis/rest/services/ORTOFOTOS/GOBIERNO_VASCO_2016_AMPLIADO/MapServer"
  })]
});

var layerBase = {
        title: "Basemap",
    baseMapLayers: [{
    url: "http://arcgis.bizkaia.eus/arcgis/rest/services/ORTOFOTOS/GOBIERNO_VASCO_2016_AMPLIADO/MapServer",
    visibility: true,
    layerType:"ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer"}]};
layer = new WMTSLayer({
          url: "http://www.ign.es/wmts/ign-base"          
        });
map = new Map({
 //basemap: Basemap.fromJSON(layerBase),
 //basemap: "streets",
 basemap: basemap,
 layers: [layer]
});

view = new MapView({
     container: "viewDiv",
     map: map
 });
 view.when(function() {
   view.extent = layer.fullExtent;
   var layerList = new LayerList({
     view: view
   });
   view.ui.add(layerList, "bottom-left");
 });
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is in the reference system (which is readonly), the above layer is not re-projected to fit over the basemap.

Comment: the layer does not have to be reprojected, is tiled layer cahed in diferen proyections, you can check in tilematrix off each layer, in this piece of code you have not set the active layer, so is getting the first one that does not have EPSG:28530 projection, so the api is not doing requests, please check this piece of code where y have set the correct active layer of the WMTSLayer that is projected  jsfiddle.net/fn5zt7hm also I have used TiledLayer, and 10.31 service as basemap.

Answer (score 0):

In this image you can check what projections are supported on IGNBaseTodo layer the layer that I am trying to use.

I have load this layer on QGIS with EPSG:28530 spatial reference and I have captured the requests and compare with the requests that arcgis API4 is doing, the unique difference is tilerow parameter, everything else is ok.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoshV.jpg)